# How to add %d to argparse help text

Tags: python, python-2.6, argparse

I am facing this problem with python 2.6.1 argparse 0.8 , I need to add `%d` to help description e.g.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--range', metavar='range', type=str,
       help='generates a list of host from given range e.g. "host%d.example.com 1 224"')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

It throws error

```
$ ./args.py  -h
...
python2.6/site-packages/argparse.py", line 458, in _expand_help
    return action.help % params
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict
```

Which I can understand, so I tried to escape `%` e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('--range', metavar='range', type=str,
       help='generates a list of host from given range e.g. "host%%d.example.com 1 224"')
```

But I still get another error

```
$ ./args.py  -h
...
python2.6/site-packages/argparse.py", line 252, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help() % dict(prog=self._prog)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict
```

So I am not sure how to escape `%` properly so that I can see `%d` in help output

Comment: You probably already know this.. Escaping with `%` works fine in 2.7

Comment: @bernie You should post it as an answer.

Comment: update your argparse version. [`%%` works](http://ideone.com/g3mgRb) in stdlib's version.

Comment: @bernie yes I know, I have tagged this question as 2.6.1 and I can not upgrade my argparse or python version

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian that is not in my control, so my question is about any specific workaround for 2.6?

Comment: The real question is what version of argparse do you have? The version I have installed for use with python 2.6 works.

Comment: Download [argparse.py](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/source/browse/argparse.py) (single file). And put it along side your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since argparse is formatting the string twice, giving 2 errors, the solution is to double-escape the `%`:

```
parser.add_argument('--range', metavar='range', type=str,
       help='generates a list of host from given range e.g. "host%%%%d.example.com 1 224"')
```

That's 4 `%`s.

Comment: it produces ["%%d" in the output instead of "%d"](http://ideone.com/nerIkD) on non-broken argparse version.

Answer (score 0):

A slight alternative if 4 `%`s offends your eye.

```
  parser.add_argument('--range', metavar='range', type=str,
        help=r'generates a list of host from given range e.g. "host%s.example.com 1 224"' % "%%d")
```